# check if string position is in the correct position in mysql

Tags: mysql, string, position

Is there a way to check if the string is in the right position?

For example for this value:

```
|       value       |
|   N, Christina    |
```

I use substring to parse the text

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ',', 1), ', ', -1)
```

But is there a way to check for the value `N, Christina` if the text 'N' is in the text and if that 'N' is in the correct position?

Comment: That really depends on how you define "correct position".

Comment: for the text `N, Christina` the position of the text is always going to be 1

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you come up with a more general rule than one applying to only one value, or are all your values `N, Christina`?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to extrapolate from your question, here's a query that checks whether a value starts with an uppercase letter, followed by a comma:

```
SELECT value, value REGEXP '^[A-Z],' AS matches
FROM your_table_name;
```

For a table with these contents:

```
|       value       |
|   N, Christina    |
|   Christina, N    |
|    J, Roberto     |
```

It will yield the following result:

```
|       value       | matches |
|   N, Christina    |    1    |
|   Christina, N    |    0    |
|    J, Roberto     |    1    |
```

Comment: oh so its only per one letter? i get 0 if its like `NA, Christina`

Comment: You have to clarify your question. It's impossible to figure out what you need exactly.